# How does one create a full-screen Text-based User Interface on first boot setup script?

Tags: software-installation, fullscreen

I'm busy creating a very specific project using a **Raspberry Pi Zero W** that is connected to a screen running 800px x 480px and a few navigation buttons (up/down/left/right/enter/back).

So on first run, it will fire up a script to show a list of available Wi-Fi networks to which it can connect as well as a few subsequent questions.

However, I do not want it to be displayed in a standard prompt, I want it displayed in a full-screen, vertically centered type of display.

hat I would like to do is on first boot create a full-screen set-up, similar to setting up phpmyadmin:

[image: phpmyadmin setup]

...or running `raspi-config` on Raspbian.

How does one go about this?

Comment: Not an answer, but this type of UI is called a [text-based user interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

Answer (score 0):

The interface used is built by `whiptail` (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail)

Useful how-to here: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-use-whiptail-to-write-interactive-shell-scripts/

Comment: Actually, it's not **whiptail** in this case, but the underlying library **newt** called directly from python scripts.